# MS11-100, MaxHttpCollectionKeys not working

Tags: web-part, web-config

Our application is  giving the following error in a large form:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.    at 
>   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded() 
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes,
>   Encoding  encoding)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()

When I investigated the problem, we found it was related to MS11-100.
The recommendationis to the following entry to the appsettings:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="36001" />
```

However, after adding the key in the Sharepoint Web Application, it is still giving the same error.
I have tried adding the key both manually in the web.config and programmatically using the SPWebConfigModification

Should this setting work in SharePoint?
Could I have something wrong in my infrastucture that SharePoint is simply not taking into consideration the web.config changes?
Any suggestions of how best to investigate this issue please?

Any assistance woul be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the full url of your page and which web.config did you modify?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my sharepoint environment, I have a number of web applications and I have modified the web.config of one of these web applications. The web applications have a separate (dedicated) application pool.